'apt' system now producing "N: Skipping acquire of configured file..."
My errors say NOTHING about "i386".
Ubuntu 22.04 - seems the problem began after retiring Cinnamon DE, replacing with MATE.
(sudo apt update)
Hit:1 https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://mirrors.namecheap.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease             
Hit:3 http://mirrors.namecheap.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease     
Hit:4 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/thierry-f/fork-michael-gruz/ubuntu jammy InRelease 
Hit:5 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ubuntuhandbook1/apps/ubuntu jammy InRelease 
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree... Done 
Reading state information... Done 
All packages are up to date. 
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-apt/Packages' as repository 'http://mirrors.namecheap.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'apt' 
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'restricted/binary-apt/Packages' as repository 'http://mirrors.namecheap.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'apt' 
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/binary-apt/Packages' as repository 'http://mirrors.namecheap.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'apt' 
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/binary-apt/Packages' as repository 'http://mirrors.namecheap.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'apt' 
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-apt/Packages' as repository 'http://mirrors.namecheap.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'apt'

"doesn't support architecture 'apt'???????"

Did you accidentally add apt as a foreign architecture? Please add the output of dpkg --print-foreign-architectures

Please add the complete contents of the 'namecheap' sources list to your question.

'namecheap' sources:      deb http://mirrors.namecheap.com/ubuntu/ jammy main restricted
deb http://mirrors.namecheap.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates main restricted
deb http://mirrors.namecheap.com/ubuntu/ jammy universe
deb http://mirrors.namecheap.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates universe
deb http://mirrors.namecheap.com/ubuntu/ jammy multiverse
deb http://mirrors.namecheap.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates multiverse

dpkg --print-foreign-architectures         produces        i386  apt

In future please edit your question with required info, don't paste it in comments.

Based on your comment

dpkg --print-foreign-architectures produces i386 apt

you have somehow erroneously added 'apt' as a foreign architecture - most likely by running dpkg --add-architecture apt as root. To undo it, run
sudo dpkg --remove-architecture apt

then check that it was successfully removed
dpkg --print-foreign-architectures

After that, you should be able to update as normal.
